# Multiple Scss variable files in Angular 15, problem loading styles

Tags: sass, angular14, angular15

I have a project in Angular 14 that uses a color palette with many style sheets and it works correctly. But when updating to Angular 15 everything stops working.

This is my Angular 14 project

[Main SCSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUyme.png)

[Mixins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BurFp.png)

[Some Theme SCSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLQMN.png)

[Main.TS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgGEg.png)

[Theme 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5AjE.png)

[Theme 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN4Wy.png)

My angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vien-angular": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [              
              "@babel/runtime/helpers/inherits",
              "@babel/runtime/helpers/construct",
              "@babel/runtime/helpers/inheritsLoose",
              "@videojs/xhr",
              "videojs-vtt.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.promise.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.regexp.to-string.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.includes.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.reverse.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.index-of.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.split.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.starts-with.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.ends-with.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.trim.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.reduce.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.array.iterator.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.replace.js",
              "core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.iterator.js",
              "core-js/modules/es.string.match.js",
              "crypto-js",
              "chart.js",
              "powerbi-client",
              "powerbi-models",
              "jspdf-autotable",
              "firebase/app",
              "raf",
              "file-saver",
              "lodash",              
              "nouislider",
              "mousetrap",
              "ngx-lightbox",
              "global/document",
              "mux.js/lib/tools/parse-sidx",
              "element-resize-detector",
              "angular-svg-round-progressbar",
              "rgbcolor",
              "dropzone",
              "quill",
              "global/window",
              "keycode",
              "mux.js/lib/utils/clock",
              "safe-json-parse/tuple",
              "moment"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist/Frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/Web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/assets/css/vendor/bootstrap.rtl.only.min.css",
              "./node_modules/@glidejs/glide/dist/css/glide.core.min.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "./node_modules/@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "./node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.css",
              "./node_modules/angular-archwizard/archwizard.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-lightbox/lightbox.css",
              "./node_modules/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css",
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.blueyale.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.blue.yale",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.bluenavy.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.blue.navy",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.blueolympic.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.blue.olympic",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.greenmoss.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.green.moss",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.greenlime.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.green.lime",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.yellowgranola.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.yellow.granola",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.greysteel.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.grey.steel",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.orangecarrot.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.orange.carrot",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.purplemonster.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.purple.monster",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.light.redruby.scss",
                "bundleName": "light.red.ruby",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.blueyale.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.blue.yale",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.bluenavy.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.blue.navy",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.blueolympic.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.blue.olympic",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.greenmoss.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.green.moss",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.greenlime.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.green.lime",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.yellowgranola.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.yellow.granola",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.greysteel.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.grey.steel",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.orangecarrot.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.orange.carrot",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.purplemonster.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.purple.monster",
                "inject": true
              },
              {
                "input": "src/assets/css/sass/themes/vien.dark.redruby.scss",
                "bundleName": "dark.red.ruby",
                "inject": true
              }
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["node_modules", "src/assets", "src"]
            },
            "scripts": [],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "15mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": ""
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vien-angular:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "vien-angular:build:production",
              "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "vien-angular:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "vien-angular:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "vien-angular:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "vien-angular",
  "version": "1.2.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "18": "^0.0.0",
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/fire": "7.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.3.0",
    "@ctrl/ngx-headroom": "^5.0.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^6.1.8",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^6.1.8",
    "@glidejs/glide": "^3.6.0",
    "@maksim_m/ngx-sortablejs": "^1.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^4.0.4",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^14.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^17.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.6",
    "angular-archwizard": "^6.1.0",
    "angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^9.0.0",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^7.0.1",
    "angular2-hotkeys": "^15.0.0",
    "angular2-notifications": "^9.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^0.0.28",
    "crypto-js": "4.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "firebase": "^9.17.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^4.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^7.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jspdf": "^2.5.1",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.7.1",
    "karma": "^6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "n": "^9.2.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^6.1.0",
    "ng2-nouislider": "^1.8.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
    "ngx-contextmenu": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-countdown": "^10.0.2",
    "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-ellipsis": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-lightbox": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-powerbi": "^3.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-smart-popover": "^1.5.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^11.0.0",
    "powerbi-client": "^2.22.2",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sortablejs": "^1.15.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.8",
    "video.js": "^7.21.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yamapng": "^2.0.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.3.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.3.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3"
  }
}
```

And my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { getThemeColor, setThemeColor } from './app/utils/util';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const color =
  environment.isMultiColorActive || environment.isDarkSwitchActive
    ? getThemeColor()
    : environment.defaultColor;

import('./assets/css/sass/themes/vien.' + color + '.scss')
  .then((x) => {
    setThemeColor(color);
    platformBrowserDynamic()
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  })
  .catch(() => {
    setThemeColor(null);
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

I see that somehow, the variables for the styles are dynamically loaded into this file.

When I update the Angular version to 15 I have the following error.

[Angular 15 Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zE5Ju.png)

I hope you can help me know how I should configure my application so that the styles load correctly.

Let me know if you need any more information.